# Current group version of Win32 GetUserNameA()?

Tags: winapi, sid

Is there a Win32 API to obtain the current user's group, i.e. the group analog to GetUserNameA()?

For example we want to switch the current group for an user in Cygwin via /usr/bin/newgrp, and then a native (non-Cygwin) application should see this change.

P.S.: What is the correct Win32 terminology for the user's current group - "primary group"?

Comment: What is primary group? I think users are members of one or more groups but there is no primary group. What you plan to in changed group?

Comment: Windows doesn't really have this concept.

Comment: user can be member of several groups. so not one but multiple. user token have so called "primary group", we can get it via TokenPrimaryGroup. but usual this is *Domain Users* ( `DOMAIN_GROUP_RID_USERS` ) and almost not used

Comment: See `NetUserGetGroups()` and `NetUserGetLocalGroups()`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetgroups Are they what you want?